# Nservicebus SagaData instances?

Tags: instance, nservicebus, saga

I am using Nservicebus sagadata for adding messages to MSMQ and I am new to it.
I have a situation where I have to check if there is any active Saga with a saga data. If there is one then I will read my object ID stored in SagaData.
So is there a way to read or check i there is a SagaData created? Does StuctureMap.ObjectFactory.Container is of any help?

Thanks in advance
Haris

Answer (score 0):

I think the answers you are looking for are documented [here](http://www.nservicebus.com/Sagas.aspx). You can also find samples of a saga in the sample applications when you download NServiceBus. HTH